# QGIS autoupdate attributes

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, events

How to change attributes value when i move(change position) point?
I don't found some information about this.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: which attributes do you mean?  The coördinates?

Comment: No. I mean attribute value, for example, was "type" = 0, i want to automaticaly change to "type" = 1

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How can values in the attribute table be refreshed automatically when a geometry changes?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103863/how-can-values-in-the-attribute-table-be-refreshed-automatically-when-a-geometry)

Comment: Also check this post: [How can I make an attribute table field automatic?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190218/how-can-i-make-an-attribute-table-field-automatic)

Comment: Thank you so much, Joseph! This is useful for me in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem as follows:
I added new another field attributes, for example, `orig_coord = concat($x,' ',$y)`
and in color rule i added this `if("orig_coord" = concat($x,' ',$y),color_rgb(0,0,0),color_rgb(0,255,50))`
So I see the color of some of the objects changed their position in the process of moving.
Again sorry for my english.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using the "Move Feature" option in QGIS, there is no way to have it automatically update have it update an attribute. If you're moving it using some kind of geoprocessing or plugin, then it depends on which tool you're using to do that.

Comment: There are ways, see for instance the AutoFields plugin.